# Why a compile type mismatch for ? extends when using an interface

Tags: java, generics

Can someone help me with an explanation as to why this is a type mismatch?

```
public interface ResponseContainer<T extends ResponsePayload<T>> {

    public T getResponsePayload();

}

public interface ResponsePayload<T> {

    public T getPayload();

}

protected abstract <T> Class<? extends ResponseContainer<? extends ResponsePayload<T>>> getResponseClazz(Class<? extends ResponsePayload<T>> responseClazz);
```

And to call it:

```
private void tryThis() {
    ResponseContainer<AccountsResponse> contaner = getResponseClazz(AccountsResponse.class); 
}
```

Gives the compilation error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#22-of ? extends ResponseContainer<? extends ResponsePayload<AccountsResponse>>> to ResponseContainer<AccountsResponse>`

Is this because I can't syntactically use ? extends T when something is implementing it rather than extending it?

Comment: you're returning `Class` but the variable is of type `ResponseContainer<AccountsResponse>`

Comment: The error message says that your `getResponseClazz` method return an object of type `Class`. `Class` is not a sub class of `ResponseContainer`. (It gets clearer if you remove all the generic types from the error message: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class to ResponseContainer`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the return type of `getResponseClazz`. You also should change your generic definition to avoid wildcards. The signature should be

```
protected abstract <T extends ResponsePayload<T>> ResponseContainer<T> getResponseContainer(Class<T> responseClazz);
```

**EDIT** Thanks to Thilo, method name changed

Comment: also change the method name to something like `getResponseContainer` or `getResponseContainerForPayloadClass` since you are not returning a class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My tryThis() was actually a bit misleading because I do actually want to return a class. It's intended to be be used for the RestTemplate `public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)` method. But I can try to use it your suggested way with getClass() on the returned object and suppress the type safety warnings passing it to the RestEntity..